Sharepoint file upload using .net core
I am working on building azure function in .net core to upload image in sharepoint using code mentioned in this post 400 Bad request when loading sharepoint site from client
As mentioned in above post, it works in .net framework, anyone had luck in making it work in .net core ? please help

check this: https://pnp.github.io/pnpcore/demos/README.html
